# Ring of formal power series and convolution

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question regarding the discrete convolution.

But first some definitions and stuff.

Let $(R,+,*)$ be a nontrivial Ring with One.
Define on $R^{\mathbb{N}}$ two operations.

1. $(p+q)_n:=p_n + q_n$
2. $(p*q)_n:=\sum\nolimits_{j=0}^np_j*q_{n-j}$

I want to show that $(R^{\mathbb{N}},+,*)$ is a Ring with one.The properties of the additive operation are shown fairly easy and the neutral element of the multiplicative operation is easy to see too.

Now comes my main question: How can i show that : $\sum\nolimits_{j=0}^np_j*q_{n-j}$ is identical with $\sum\nolimits_{k+j=n}p_k*q_j$ where of course in the last part we sum over the set $\{(k,j)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}|k+j=n\}$

Every helpful comment is appreciated!

Comment: You are summing the same numbers.

Comment: In particular i am searching for a bijection between the sets i am summing over.

Comment: Let $k=n-j$? Don't they just become the same sum?

Comment: @Dan: $j$ on the left gives $p_j q_{n-j}$, so corresponds to $(j,n-j)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: got it guys... 
thanks for the help